# Importing firebase in non-root file of React Native causes error in Android emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I create project.

```
react-native init test
```

Then:

```
yarn add firebase
```

After react-native init process I have index.js in root directory. Its contents:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => App);
```

Importing firebase in there is absolutely working case.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import firebase from 'firebase';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => App);
```

But when I try to import firebase in App.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase'; // Anywhere in this file

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        const config = {
            // data from firebase portal
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    render() {

        return (

                <View>
                    <Text>
                        Hello.
                    </Text>
                </View>

        );

    }
}

export default App;
```

I get an error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
throwOnInvalidObjectType...
```

This problem exists only in Android simulator. In iOS simulator everything is ok. 
Android Studio - the latest version.
React native - the latest version.
Firebase - the latest version.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the version 5.0.2. Use this command as administrator:

```
npm install --save firebase@5.0.2
```

As far as i see, the current version (5.0.4) is buggy!

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day. )) It helped. Obviously, Firebase of version 5.0.4 has bugs indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In firebase version ^5.3.1

Importing firebase:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
```

Work for me!